# wordpress custom contact form issue

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have created a custom contact us form for my wordpress site which should work around every single static page of my site.

So i put the html in header.php just below the body tag, appended the style.css file of the activated theme and put the css code for the form below and added the jquery code in `footer.php` and hence the form is being displayed nicely with all effects as i wanted.

But the main issue is that i am using a [captcha](https://code.google.com/p/cool-php-captcha/) inside the form which uses a `captcha.php` in the `img` tag like this `src="captcha.php"`.

Also for the mailing part i used a `mail.php` file which is verifying the captcha and do the mail(i used php mail function) and i put them in the root directory. Hence the form is working fine only for the index page.

But whenever i go to any other page the form displays correctly without the captcha as it gives an 404 for the image file only as `path/captcha.php` is not found and hence the captcha image is not loading. Please help me to sort out this problem.

I also wanted to redirect after the mail to few specific thank you pages and so obviously i want to it dynamically.

Like say i am in the about us page i,e myurl/about-us and when i submit the form... the `mail.php` will redirect me to about-us page styled a static thankyou page which i'll be creating mannualy.

Kindly do not suggest me to use CF7 as i am not interested to use and modify it for now.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your main issue is one where the directory structure isn't being taken into account.

Try referencing the captcha by using `<img src="<? bloginfo('url'); ?>/captcha.php" alt="Captcha" />`.

To include the `mail.php` on all pages, move it to the theme folder and prepend the include with `get_template_directory_uri()`. It might look like this:

```
include( get_template_directory_uri() . '/mail.php');
```

What these functions do are ensure that the files are included, no matter their relative position to the file that's calling them. [A little more reading on paths is available here](http://www.boogiejack.com/server_paths.html), if you're interested.

Finally, here are the two wp codex entries for the functions included in my answer:

[get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)
[bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo)

Comment: Thanks Cameron. My captcha is now working fine. But i added in my form tag action="<? bloginfo('url'); ?>/mail.php" and now the mail is also working fine..Now i have only one issue i,e suppose if visitors fill form from page say www.mysite.com/software-development-services/ must me redirected to www.mysite.com/software-development-services-thank-you. To accomplish this i have added a php header function below the mail function like this: $redirect_url = bloginfo('url');header("Location: $redirect_url"."-thank-you"); and its not working. Please help me out to get rid of it.

Comment: Append the `$redirect_url` with `/software-development-services-thank-you`

Comment: but before i do append its already throwing an error as call  to undefined function bloginfo. Is theres any other alternative ? What i actually want to do is retreive the page's url then redirect the user to that url-thank-you page... so that they can see the thank you page for that particular page from where they have filled the contact form.

Comment: I think you should post a new question, and in it, the file itself, so that we can troubleshoot easier!

Answer (score 0):

If your path to the captcha file is truly `src="captcha.php"`, then you could be getting a 404 because it needs to start with a preceding slash `(src="/captcha.php")`.  If you are using wordpress seo, then it would be looking for the captcha file in each directory otherwise.